# Material-ui color customization

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the background color of my paper for my footer using material-ui with React. I followed the color sample demo with createMuiTheme and then used MuiThemeProvider, but it didn't work. Do I need to use Drawer to get this to work?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';

 const style = {
  textAlign: 'center'
}

 const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
   primary: green,
   secondary: {
     main: '#2e7d32',
   },
  },
 });


 const Footer = () => {
    return(
     <React.Fragment>
       <CssBaseline />
        <Paper style={style} elevation={1}>
         <MuiThemeProvider theme = {theme}>
          <h2>Copywright Medicinal Foods 2019!</h2>
            <h3>All Rights Reserved!</h3>
              <h4>Thanks for visitng!</h4>
                <br></br>
                  <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                   </MuiThemeProvider>
                  </Paper>
                </React.Fragment>
   );
 }

 export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. You provided a `MuiThemeProvider` but it is not wrapping the `Paper`. But you want change the style of `Paper`. You have to make sure that `MuiThemeProvider` is a parent of the components you are trying to customize. [See docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#theme-provider).
2. `Paper`'s background color is not affected by the `palette.primary` or `palette.secondary`. It takes the color from `palette.background.paper`. See the [default theme here](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/).

Here is a demo, hope it helps.

```js
const {createMuiTheme, green, CssBaseline, Paper, MuiThemeProvider
} = window['material-ui'];

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
  },
  palette: {
   background: {paper: '#5fba7d'}
  },
});

 const Footer = () => {
    return(
     <React.Fragment>
       <CssBaseline />
       <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Paper elevation={1}>
          <h2>Copywright Medicinal Foods 2019!</h2>
          <h3>All Rights Reserved!</h3>
          <h4>Thanks for visitng!</h4>
        </Paper>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
     </React.Fragment>
   );
 }

ReactDOM.render(<Footer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div id="root"></div>
```